# I can't get my sprites to trigger a collider at all in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, 2d, collider

I am trying to get one sprite(the player) to trigger a function when colliding with another object that is getting cloned and put into random places within the play field. I have my player collider set to being a regular collider with a rigidbody2D attached. The object to collect here is marked as a trigger, is kinematic, has the OnTriggerEnter function attached(which most other scripts have at this point just to see if it would work), and not a single thing has changed anything about how the game runs or works or anything it seems. What am I missing?

Comment: If it's 2D are you using Collider2D and OnTeiggerEnter2D?

Comment: Share your code and. Picture of the player components and whatever it is you should be hitting

Comment: @derHugo I had no idea that Collider2D and OnTriggerEnter2D was a thing, I'll try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a comment on the main post, I found the answer. I simply didn't know that Collider2D and OnTriggerEnter2D was a thing, and once fixing that, I was able to solve the issue!